# Do either of the following series converge: $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots(2n-1)}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots{2n}}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Does $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\cdots{2n-1}}{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots{2n}}$$  converge and additionally does the following converge $$\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1^2\cdot3^2\cdot5^2\cdots{(2n-1)}^2}{2^2\cdot4^2\cdot6^2\cdots{(2n)}^2}$$

Comment: There's this guy called Wallis.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:**
$$ \frac{1\cdot3\cdot5\dots{2n-1}}{2\cdot4\cdot6\dots{2n-2}}= \frac{3}{2}  \frac{5}{4}... \frac{2n-1}{2n-2} >1$$

Comment: But what about the term $\frac{1}{2n}$? Doesn't that make it less than 1?

Comment: @user39493 What happens when you multiply BOTH sides by the missing term ;)

Comment: Then the series is greater than $\frac{1}{2n}$ which is divergent so the series diverges! Any intuition about part 2?

Comment: For the second sum, your individual terms tend to $\frac{2}{\pi}$ (as mentioned in the comments), so clearly the sum can not converge.

Comment: @user39493 Pedro gave you a good hing for part 2, look for Wallis product ;) There is probably a more elemntary solution but I cannot see it, Wallis product actually also solves this first part....

Comment: @D.Clark Actually the problem is a little more subtle that that. The Wallis product is not exactly the one given, it only has $2n$ instead of $(2n)^2$. one has to be very careful with infinite products/sums and use the proper partial sum..... To use the Wallis product, one needs to limit compare with $\frac{2}{\pi (2n)}$... Or simpler $\frac{1}{2n}$.

Comment: Wouldn't the second series need to be multiplied by $2n$ to be considered the Walli product? (Which would mean that we couldn't conclude anything about divergence since it has greater partial sums).

Comment: Oops, I missed that, you're right. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Hmm, so it turns out we can't use the Wallis product for the second part then.

Comment: @user39493 Yes.. So you are missing $(2n)$ to get $\frac{2}{\pi}$.... Which suggests the limit comparison test with $\frac{1}{2n}$.

Comment: Doesn't that converge to $0$ which leaves us unable to make a conclusion about the convergence of the series?

Comment: Nevermind, I understand. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @user39493 If you compare the given series with $\frac{1}{2n}$, the ratio is exactly the Wallis product...Which means that the given series behaves like $\sum \frac{1}{2n}$ ;)

Comment: @user39493 It was Pedro who gave you the hint for this part ;) And, by using the Wallis product you can actually limit compare the first series with $\sum \frac{1}{\sqrt{2n}}$, so his hint solves both parts, but my hint for part one is more "elementary"...

Comment: It seems that $(n-1)$ should be replaced by $(2n-1)$.

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}
 \newcommand{\wt}[1]{\widetilde{#1}}$
$\ds{\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
     {1\cdot 3\cdot 5 \cdots \pars{2n-1} \over 2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots\pars{2n}}:\
     {\large ?}\,,\qquad\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty}
     \bracks{1\cdot 3\cdot 5 \cdots \pars{2n-1}
     \over 2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots\pars{2n}}^{2}:\ {\large ?}}$

> Note that
>   $$
> {1\cdot 3\cdot 5 \cdots \pars{2n-1} \over 2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots\pars{2n}}
> ={1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdot 4\cdot 5 \cdots \pars{2n-1}\pars{2n}
>   \over \bracks{2\cdot4\cdot6\cdots\pars{2n}}^{2}}
> ={1 \over 4}\,{\pars{2n}! \over n!^{2}} = {1 \over 4}\,{2n \choose n}
> $$

When $\ds{n \gg 1}$:
\begin{align}
{1 \over 4}\,{2n \choose n}&\approx
{1 \over 4}\,{\root{2\pi}\pars{2n}^{2n + 1/2}\expo{-2n}
\over \bracks{\root{2\pi}n^{n + 1/2}\expo{-n}}^{2}}=
{2^{2n - 2} \over \root{\pi}}\,{1 \over n^{1/2}} \stackrel{n \to \infty}{\Large \to} +\infty
\\[3mm]
{1 \over 16}\,{2n \choose n}^{2}&\approx
{2^{4n - 4} \over \pi}\,{1 \over n} \stackrel{n \to \infty}{\Large \to} +\infty
\end{align}